# Showing a set of points on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a set that is defined as the following

$$
S = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z + 5 + i| > 1 \}
$$

And I am to show the region of $z$ on the complex plane.

I'm not entirely sure where to start with this one. I'm pretty sure that it is a circular region but I'm really not sure how to get the boundary values.

Comment: Hint. If $w=-5-i$, then $z\in S\Rightarrow |z-w|>1$.

Comment: All the points outside the closed disk around $-5-i$ with radius $1$.

Comment: The previous comments provide the elegant approach.  The pedestrian approach is to consider the alternatives of $z = re^{i\theta}$ and $z = x + iy$.  In a problem like this, if elegance eludes me, I would opt for $z = x + iy$, and try to establish a relationship between $x$ and $y$ for all satisfying values of $z$.

Comment: First consider what $|z|>1$ would like. Notice how we are simply translating this region by $5+i$, or more precisely $-(5+i)$.